# Distance measurement

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, spatial-analyst, ndvi

I have calculated NDVI, now I would like to measure the distance from the places which have more vegetation concentration to low to bare concentration areas. which tool in ArcGIS 10.2 will be suitable to measure the distance (in metres)?

Comment: What have you tried so far and where are you getting stuck? What is the question you are trying to answer? We really don't have enough info to help you as the question is written.

Comment: Please define what you mean by "unsheltered".

Comment: A threat to erosion due to lack of shelter/vegetation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to Reclassify your raster based on NDVI values, like if NDVI is greater than 55 then that is vegetation otherwise no vegetation. However this marks any low lying cells as vegetation, grass, paddocks, etc.  not only trees. Then, if your places are in vector format (e.g. point, polygon) I would use Buffer tool with a buffer distance of preference and run [Zonal Statistics as Table](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/zonal-statistics-as-table.htm) tool to tally land cover according to Reclassify-ied raster values.

Answer (score 1):

Reclassify your NDVI raster, setting the barren areas (NDVI <= 0?) to NoData.  Then run the euclidean distance tool which will fill those empty areas with distance-to-vegetation.  The distances will be in meters if your coordinate reference system is in meters, so be sure to set that first.